# Node.js 502 No Access Control Allow Origin Specified

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node.JS and wanted to build an basic API. The problem here is whenever I make a HTTP request I get this error message.

'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8001' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 502.

Here is the code :

```
var server = https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://localhost:8001'); // client address
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        req.on('data', function(data) {
            data = data + '';
            data = data.split('&');
            if(data[0].slice(7) == 'id'){
                var credentials = {};
                credentials.username = data[1].slice(9);
                credentials.password = data[2].slice(9);
                api.login(credentials.username, credentials.password, function(err, response) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else if (response === true) {
                        var token = success()
                        res.writeHead(200);
                        res.end(token);
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-origin is in 'https' but you are requesting from 'http'

Comment: 502 is Bad Gateway. If you have a reverse proxy like Nginx in front of your Node server, there’s likely something wrong with its configuration. If you try the request manually (just in your browser, without AJAX), does it work? (And yes, `http` vs. `https` is going to matter too.)